# MYSQL: Group By and SUM different columns with different criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query a MySQL table with GROUP BY, and then SUM columns based on different criteria (type).

Here is a table:

```
NAME       TYPE      AMOUNT

Walter     BUY       2
Walter     BUY       5
Walter     SELL      3
Walter     SELL      1
Pollo      BUY       8 
Pollo      BUY       2 
Jessie     BUY       1
Jessie     BUY       3
Jessie     SELL      2
Jessie     SELL      1
```

I'm want to group by name and SUM the BUY and SELL for each name. The result I'm looking for:

```
Name       SUM(BUY)    SUM(SELL)

Jessie     4           3
Pollo      10          0
Walter     7           4
```

I'm able to achieve the SUM but only on two different queries:

```
 SELECT name, SUM(BUY) FROM tb WHERE TYPE = "BUY" GROUP BY NAME;

 SELECT name, SUM(SELL) FROM tb WHERE TYPE = "SELL" GROUP BY NAME;
```

I'm trying to UNION and UNION ALL these queries but it's not working:

```
 (SELECT name, SUM(BUY) FROM tb WHERE TYPE = "BUY" GROUP BY NAME)
 UNION
 (SELECT name, SUM(SELL) FROM tb WHERE TYPE = "SELL" GROUP BY NAME);
```

Is it possible to GROUP BY and then SUM different columns with different WHERE condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to use the condition aggregate function

use `SUM` and `CASE WHEN` expressions with your logic.

```
SELECT name, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'buy' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) 'SUM(BUY)',
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Sell' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) 'SUM(Sell)'
FROM tb  
WHERE TYPE IN ('buy','Sell')
GROUP BY NAME;
```

[sqfliddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=847e002e422157cb08661dc2d7e517e8)

Comment: I don't know whether MySQL has a PIVOT operator, but this looks like _exactly_ what PIVOT is good for.

Comment: @AnnL. Yes condition aggregate function is able to instead pivot.